# How can I add button (close/stop) on top of the Notiflix.Loading() overlay?

Tags: javascript, html, css, npm

I am using **"notiflix"** library in my project in which I've used `notiflix.loading.pulse()` for a long running process and which is perfectly okay but I need a Button (close/stop process) upon overlay of that notiflix.loading().

How can I customise overlay and put Button on it? (Please refer below image which depicts overlay coming on whole page while using `notiflix.loading.pulse()`, I just want to put HTML button on this overlay)

[Please refer this link for notiflix](https://www.notiflix.com/)

[image]

Comment: I've taken a look at their documentation and it doesn't look like they provide you with the ability to add a close button via their API. You would most likely have to code this to only come in when the loading box pops up and have it hide their notification once the button is clicked. Their documentation: https://www.notiflix.com/documentation - has a generator for you which outputs the code which you would use for customisation.

Comment: Already I went through their document and didn't found anything that is why I put this here.. so someone who was stuck with same and got the solution can help me. And yeah appreciate your concern. I'll close this if not found anything.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly what you mean, but you can use the function

```
Notiflix.Loading.Remove();
```

And then the loading screen dissapears, i hope my answer is useful :).

Also you can read examples in readme.md file in the github repo.
https://github.com/notiflix/Notiflix